# Clearing screen at key press in GLUT, c++

Tags: c++, opengl, glut

I have a program that monitors a text file for changes, and upon detecting one, the user has the option to redisplay the screen based on the contents of this text file. My problem is that when a new screen is requested, the contents of the previous screen stay, while the new contents overlaps it. I want the screen to be cleared before new data is put on the screen.

here is what I have:

```
void keyboard(unsigned char key, int x, int y){
    if(key == 'c'){
        c_pressed++;
        cout<<"c pressed: "<<c_pressed<<"sound.txt cleared..."<<endl;
        clear_file();
    }
    if(key=='v'){
        v_pressed++;
        cout<<"v pressed: "<<v_pressed<<"displaying new configuration..."<<endl;
        glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
        glutPostRedisplay();
    }
}
```

When the key 'c' is pressed, the text file is cleared. I have verified this works properly. Then after a separate program loads in new data into the text file, the user presses 'v' to load these new instructions. I've tried placing the clear function within the 'v' statement, and as well as in the display function...

```
void display(void){ 
    glClearColor(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT|GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    read_in_sound();    
    cout<<"Number of sound events:  "<<numLines<<endl;

    for(int j=0; j<numLines; j++){
        if(data[0+j*4]==1){
            circle(0,0,200,50);
        }

        if(data[1+j*4]==1){
            circle(0,400,200,50);
        }

        if(data[2+j*4]==1){
            circle(400,400,200,50);
        }

        if(data[3+j*4]==1){
            circle(400,0,200,50);
        }       
    }
    glFlush();
    glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

But when I call redisplay, both the old and new screens are displayed.

Answer (score 2):

As a general rule you should do OpenGL drawing calls (and clearing the scene is a drawing call) only from the display function. If something in a OpenGL scene changes the canonical way is to redraw the whole thing. So in reaction to any event you change your programs state and issue a redraw, which will ultimately redraw the scene using OpenGL.

If the scene is very complex any you want to only update the scene with only opaque geometry (anything that requires blending mandates a full redraw) you should use store the scene color and depth buffer to textures and use them to start from a well defined state. Ideally you use a framebuffer object for this.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be the best method in the world, but I added a rectangle object that is the size of the window that matches the black background that gets called up each time I want to "redraw". It saves time from having to write in a framebuffer like the previous answer suggested.